# Access denied in workgroup for UNC

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing, unc

I have two Windows Server 2008 machines: machine1 and machine2. They are both in a workgroup but not in a domain.

On both machines I have the user accounts 'Administrator' and 'FileTestUser' with the SAME passwords on both machines. 'FileTestUser' is member of Users and Administrators. 'Administrator' is the administrator.

I want to write on share d$ on machine2, i.e. I want to access the files via UNC from machine1:

```
\\machine2\d$\test.txt
```

When impersonating machine2\Administrator it works. When impersonating 'FileTestUser' it doesn't. How can I connect to the remote drive NOT using my administrator accounts?

Comment: Create a proper file share with permissions for that user.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work via $d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `C$`, `D$`, etc., shares are literally called *Administrative Shares*.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share):

> Administrative shares cannot be accessed by users without administrative privileges.

You need to create a new share for the users, that is not a built-in administrative share.

(That the two accounts have the same password is wholly irrelevant.)

Comment: FileTestUser is member of the group Administrators. Doesn't that imply the user has administrative privileges?

Comment: `Machine2\FileTestUser`, if the user is in the Administrators group on `Machine2`, can access the administrative share of `Machine2`. `Machine1\FileTestUser` cannot be in the local Administrators group on `Machine2`.

Comment: Using a file share works! I didn't know about the "Administrative Shares" and their specialities.